# Reverse int function Returning inf

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

```
a = 123

def rev(n):
    r = 0
    while n>0:
        r *= 10
        r += n % 10
        n /= 10
    return r

print(rev(a))
```

while I was Running this code on python2 it worked fine. 
but after that i tried to run it on python3 it returns

```
inf
```

what i missed?

Sorry For Poor English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 3 changed the way division works on integers.

In Python 2, `15/10` gives `1` (floor division).

In Python 3, `15/10` gives `1.5` (true division).

Your Python 2 code was using floor division, which in Python 3 requires the `//` operator.

So change

```
n /= 10
```

to

```
n //= 10
```